# Using Mathematica to find the eigenvectors

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, wolfram-cloud

I would like some clarification about solving for eigenvectors in Mathematica.

I am looking at the following matrix:

\begin{equation*}
L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & m(1+\frac{kmwr}{\lambda}) \\
q(1-kpx) & k \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

where $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue. From reading some notes, the dominant left eigenvector should be $[q \: \:\lambda]$. What is the simplest way to reach this in Mathematica (and for other similar matrix problems)? The following `Eigensystem[]` call produces a complicated-looking function that does not seem to match  $[q \:\: \lambda]$:

```
L={{0, m(1+(k m w r)/lambda)},
{q(1- k p x),k}}

Eigensystem[L]
```

I would appreciate some enlightenment here about how to find the eigenvectors in Mathematica.

Comment: Simply use "Eigenvectors[L]"

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried it. Eigenvectors[L] also produces the same long functions. I can't see how I'd realise from looking at them that the result I want is $[q \: \lambda]$

Comment: `q lambda`  is a scalar, not a "dominant eigenvector"

Comment: It’s a vector with two elements, $q$ and $\lambda$

Comment: Multiply  L by {q,lambda}: `L . {q,lamda}`and you see that it is not an eigenvector.

Comment: Ah. You're right. It is the dominant *left* eigenvector. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you say `lambda` is the dominant eigenvalue, but it's part of the matrix `L`.  The dominant eigenvalue isn't usually built into the matrix like this.  If you run `FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[L]]`, you will see that `lambda` is not actually an eigenvalue of `L`.

Comment: To get left eigenvectors/eigenvalues, transpose the matrix (provided none of the entries are complex), so do `Eigensystem@Transpose@L`. You can see that the eigenvalues of this matrix *do not* include $\lambda$ (the expressions don't simplify). Perhaps there's some special interpretation of "dominant" here? I think of the dominant eigenvalue as the *largest* eigenvalue of the matrix, but perhaps it means something different for you?